# 3n+1 giving negative numbers

Tags: c#, collatz

I recently found out about the 3n+1 problem and wanted to write a simple code to do the problem.

It all works but at high odd numbers such as 999,999,999 it goes to negative numbers and repeats an endless cycle and I have no clue why.

```
// if n is odd  n = 3n+1
// if n is even n = n/2
while (true)
{
    int n;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a positive whole number greater than one: ");
    while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a positive whole number greater than one: ");
    }
    while (n != 1)
    {
        if (n % 2 == 0)
        {
            n /= 2;
            Console.WriteLine("n / 2     = " + n);
        }
        else
        {
            n = 3 * n + 1;
            Console.WriteLine("3 * n + 1 = " + n);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Clear();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you are running into [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

Comment: The [collatz conjeture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) has been checked for all number smaller than 87×2^60 (via the yoyo@home project) - you need integers with more than [66 bits](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln_2(87%C3%972%5E60)) to compete. int32 and int64 are too small. Use [decimal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal) ([10^28 ~> 2^93](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln_2(10%5E28))) or [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx). Edit: disregarding runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening due to *integer overflow*:

> In computer programming, an integer overflow occurs when an arithmetic
>   operation attempts to create a numeric value that is outside of the
>   range that can be represented with a given number of bits – either
>   larger than the maximum or lower than the minimum representable value.

You could make use of a 64-bit integer type, in order to have a bigger range of integer numbers. Apparently an overflow can be noticed also in the latter case, but it will happen in a very large number. With 64-bit integer you can represent

```
18,446,744,073,709,551,615 numbers
```

Whereas with 32-bit integers you can represent

```
4,294,967,295 numbers
```

In case of `Int32` and `Int64` you should divide the above numbers by two and take the quotient, this would be the *maximum positive number* that can be represented. This should be done, because both `Int32` and `Int64` are signed integers.

A better approach would be to make use of `UInt64`, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint64(v=vs.110).aspx), which can be used to represent unsigned integers with values ranging from 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.

Definetely an overflow can be noticed also in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`int` is maximum `2,147,483,647`. `3n` when `n` is `999,999,999` is going to be bigger and overflow which will cause `n` to be negative after `n = 3 * n + 1;`